# how to convert Json date format into datetime format(mm/dd/yyyy))?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

My jquery function returning date in json format,so i want to know how to convert this into datetime formate "mm/dd/yyyy"

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date1;
DateTime.TryParseExact(formCollection["date"], "MM/dd/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None, out date1);
```

1. it will not throw any exception.
2. if there is wrong format, you can compare with `DateTime.MinValue`, that is it succesfully converted.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I format a Microsoft JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-json-date)

You can use this to get a date from json:

```
var date = eval(jsonDate.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
```

and then you can use [JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) script (1.2 KB when minified and gzipped) to display it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no date data type in [JSON](http://www.json.org/), so what you have is a date formatted as a string. Use the `ParseExact` method to parse the string into a `DateTime` value.

Then you can use the `ToString` method or `String.Format` method using the pattern `MM'/'dd'/'yyyy` to format the `DateTime` value into a string.